# LinqPad Linq Include() extension method is not found even after adding references

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I am able to do

```
var result =  OAS_Questions.Count (oasq => oasq.Id!=0);
result.Dump();
```

and even

```
var result =  OAS_Questions;
result.Dump();
```

But when I try to include child objects of "Questions" say "Opitons" through

```
var result =  OAS_Questions.Include("OAS_QuestionOptions");
result.Dump();
```

I am shown the below error

> 'System.Data.Linq.Table' does not contain
>   a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting
>   a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table' could be found
>   (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

I have already tried adding references to the below assembly references.

1. System.Code
2. System.Data
3. System.Data.Entity
4. System.Data.Linq
5. System.Linq.Expressions
6. System.Data.DataSetExtensions

But still the extension method "Include()" is not available while composing query and it gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 40):

If you're using EF via LinqPad then a better method is to use the strongly typed version of `.Include` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28VS.103%29.aspx) as follows:

1. open your LinqPad Query
2. right-click -> query properties
3. Add reference to the `EntityFramework.dll`
4. via the Additional namespace import tab add `System.Data.Entity`

you then have intellisense and can use the strongly typed version of .Include, e.g.:

```
var result =  OAS_Questions.Include(q => q.OAS_QuestionOptions);
```

Comment: For Entity Framework Core add reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll assembly and add additional namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: No. OP is in LINQ-to-SQL, as other answers indicate correctly. Adding references won't do anything.

Answer (score 12):

You need to use a Typed DataContext (`ObjectContext` or `DbContext`) from your EntityFramework project's DLL. You can do this by performing the following steps:

1. Click on the **Add Connection** link in the top-left corner of the application.
2. In the `Choose Data Context` wizard, select the `Use a typed data context from your own assembly` option.
3. Click on the LINQPad Driver option appropriate for your solution (LINQ to SQL, EF 4.0 and lower or EF 4.1 and higher), then click **Next**.
4. Click `Browse` in the top-right corner and navigate to then select your EF project assembly.
5. Select the Entity Data Model, then click **OK**.
6. Specify the `Server`, `Log on details` and `database`, then click **OK**.

You should now be able to use the `.Include` statement in LinqPad.

Answer (score 5):

By default Linqpad uses Linq2Sql DataContext which doesn't let you do an include.

To get the include extension method use a Typed DataContext from your project assembly (EF4.x /EF5)

Comment: See here for an explanation of how to add the reference to the Typed DataContext: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24456720/1943